# Getting dictionary from arrays obtained as response in swift 3

Tags: arrays, swift3

I am trying to populate a view from the response obtained from server.The response obtained are as follows:

```
["data": <__NSArrayM 0x60800024a440>(
{
    "brand_name" = Levis;
    category = Accessories;
    discountprice = 0;
    images =     (
                {
            image = "HTTP://i.vinove.com/dnn/backend/uploads/954tshirt_PNG5434.png";
        }
    );
    name = clothes;
    price = "23.00";
    "product_id" = PRO161519;
},
{
    "brand_name" = test;
    category = Accessories;
    discountprice = 0;
    images =     (
                {
            image = "HTTP://i.vinove.com/dnn/backend/uploads/wristwatch.jpg";
        }
    );
    name = Watches;
    price = "23.00";
    "product_id" = PRO361521;
}
)
, "message": Successfull, "code": 200, "totalItem": 2]
```

My question is how can i obtain the value of images from this reponse and use the values against image to populate my imageviews.

I have done this much,but not able to get the desired value as I don't understand that how can i get the dictionary values from array in swift 3.Kindly help me with your suggestions.Thanks in advance!

```
  func getResponseFromService(){
        var params = [String:Any]()
        params["child_id"]="25"
        params["limit"]="10"
        params["method"] = "product_list"
        params["offset"]="0"
        params["parent_id"]="1"
        WebServiceHelper.sharedInstance.webHelper(params, url: webServicesUrl) {
            (response, success)
            in
            print("get response",response)
            var array : [Any]
            array = [response["data"] as Any]
            for item in array{
                print("value of item returned",array.first as Any)
             print("value of array returned",array.count)
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like this :

```
func getResponseFromService(){
    var params = [String:Any]()
    params["child_id"]="25"
    params["limit"]="10"
    params["method"] = "product_list"
    params["offset"]="0"
    params["parent_id"]="1"
    WebServiceHelper.sharedInstance.webHelper(params, url: webServicesUrl) {
        (response, success)
        in
        print("get response",response)
        for dict in response["data"]! {
            var item = dict as! [String: Any]
            print(item["brand_name"])
            print(item["category"])
            print(item["discountprice"])
        }
    }
}
```